# Scriptblock function parameter containing $_ not working inside module

Tags: powershell

I have created a function which has a `[scriptblock]` parameter and I call it with a scriptblock that contains the `$_` automatic variable. Like this:

```
function Test-ScriptBlock {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][PSObject] $InputObject,
        [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock
    )
    $_ = $input
    Invoke-Command $ScriptBlock
}
```

If I call the function by dot-sourcing a .ps1 file containing the function or pasting the function code directly at the command prompt, it works fine:

```
3,2,1 | Test-ScriptBlock -ScriptBlock {$_ | Sort-Object}
1
2
3
```

However, if I add the function to a module and import it, it doesn't work anymore:

```
3,2,1 | Test-ScriptBlock -ScriptBlock {$_ | Sort-Object}
<nothing>
```

I had to change the code like this to make it work:

```
function Test-ScriptBlockModule {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][PSObject] $InputObject,
        [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock
    )
    $_ = $input
    Invoke-Command ([scriptblock]::Create($ScriptBlock))
}
```

So it looks like the issue is when the scriptblock gets evaluated ? If I force a recreation of the passed scriptblock after $_ has been set inside the module function, it works. But I don't really know why it only does this inside a module ?

I'm sure some PowerShell guru can explain this to me !

Comment: Module-scope is supremely confusing in PowerShell. You'll want to call: `$ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $input))`

Comment: I’m sure this has something to do with the `$input` variable but lacks awareness of what’s going on.

Comment: This is a simplified example, I have also tried without the `$input` variable, using the `$InputObject` parameter instead. The fact that it works fine outside of a module seems to indicate it has to do with module scope rules...

Comment: The same behaviour can be observed if you replace `$_ = $input` with `$_ = @('Z', 'Y', 'X')`